# Installing Haskell cairo on Windows

Tags: haskell, installation, cairo, cabal

I am trying to install cairo on Windows XP and this is the command that I am trying:

```
cabal install cairo --extra-include-dirs="C:\cygwin\usr\include" --extra-lib-dirs="C:\cygwin\lib" --extra-include-dirs="C:\cygwin\usr\include\cairo"
```

And the full output that I get [can be seen at this pastie](http://hpaste.org/44021/cairo_windows_fail) but the real error is this:

> Registering cairo-0.12.0...
>   setup.exe: cairo-0.12.0: include-dirs: /usr/include/cairo doesn't exist or
>   isn't a directory (use --force to override)
>   cairo-0.12.0: include-dirs: /usr/include/pixman-1 doesn't exist or isn't a
>   directory (use --force to override)
>   cairo-0.12.0: include-dirs: /usr/include/freetype2 doesn't exist or isn't a
>   directory (use --force to override)
>   cairo-0.12.0: include-dirs: /usr/include/libpng12 doesn't exist or isn't a
>   directory (use --force to override)
>   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   cairo-0.12.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

I know that those directories do not exist but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get it to look at the right directories. Does anybody know how I can get this install to work? Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default distribution of GHC targets native (well, mingw) executables.  These cannot be mixed with Cygwin libraries.

You'll have to use a native (non-Cygwin) installation of Cairo.

Comment: Wow really? Well that feels like a whole lot more effort than it is worth. Maybe I'll just stick with linux dev for that code until is easier to acquire on Windows. Or until somebody finally writes a pure Haskell vector graphics library.

Comment: @Robert: If you really want, it's probably still possible to build GHC-cygwin (e.g. GHC targeting Cygwin).  But it's very unsupported.  Personally, I would recommend ignoring Windows forever.

Comment: Yeah. It's really not worth my time to be trying to get things working on Windows. But what really needs to happen here is more Pure Haskell libraries that will just work everywhere.

Comment: This sucks. A lot. Could it produce a MORE descriptive error than stupid "ExitFailure 1".